# Página de login em SPA's (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, front-end

No cenário atual, eu tenho uma index.html que funciona como uma espécie de template. Por exemplo, nela eu tenho um menu lateral, uma barra de ferramentas no topo e, ao "centro", uma div (ng-view) para receber o conteúdo dinâmico.

A questão é que a tela de login não tem nada a ver com essa "template". Ela tem suas próprias características. Neste caso, qual seria a melhor abordagem? Pensei em algumas soluções, mas gostaria da opinião de alguém mais experiente com SPA's.

Comment: Eu particularmente deixaria a `index` apenas com uma `ui-view` central e controlaria por `states`. Assim, após autenticar o usuário, você teria o que atualmente é seu `index` e que contém a "moldura" por assim dizer das suas páginas

Comment: Certo, essa foi a minha idéia inicial, realmente. Como ficaria a implementação disso? Digo, cada uma das minhas páginas dinâmicas (cadastro de contatos, por exemplo) deverá conter o conteúdo dela + o que hoje faz parte da template (sidebar, toolbar,etc.) ?

Comment: Não exatamente. Você pode ter uma `ui-view` dentro da outra. Você está trabalhando com `ui-router`?

Comment: Estou usando 'ngRoute'.

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nesse link com as diferenças](http://afonsof.com/blog/principais-diferencas-entre-o-ngroute-e-o-ui-router/) entre o ui-router e o ngRoute, a diferença mais forte pra mim é na parte das múltiplas `views`. Sem elas você não vai conseguir fazer o que eu tava descrevendo aqui de forma satisfatória

Comment: Perfeito! Exatamente o que precisava.

Comment: Vou ver se consigo colocar um exemplo na resposta, assim você pode ver mais ou menos como fica